# Should ReadOnlySpan<T> parameters use the "in" modifier?

Tags: c#, performance, c#-7.2

C# 7.2 introduced [reference semantics with value-types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types), and alongside this Microsoft have developed types like [`Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/docs/specs/span.md) to potentially improve performance for apps that need to perform operations on contiguous regions of memory.

According to the docs, one way of potentially improving performance is to pass immutable structs by reference by adding an `in` modifier to parameters of those types:

```
void PerformOperation(in SomeReadOnlyStruct value)
{
}
```

What I'm wondering is whether I ought to do this with types like `ReadOnlySpan<T>`. Should I be declaring methods that accept a read-only span like this:

```
void PerformOperation<T>(in ReadOnlySpan<T> value)
{
}
```

or simply like:

```
void PerformOperation<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> value)
{
}
```

Will the former offer any performance benefits over the latter? I couldn't find any documentation that explicitly advises in either direction, but I did find [this example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2018/03/02/c-7-series-part-9-ref-structs/) where they demonstrated a method that accepts a `ReadOnlySpan` and *did not* use the `in` modifier.

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference, however set up some benchmarks and let us know

Comment: @MarcGravell That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: I'll see if I can get some benchmarks set up.

Comment: Very different concepts.  The `in` keyword provides a possible optimization to pass large structure types by reference but not pay for the cost of having to copy it back to the caller.  ReadOnlySpan is not large, using `in` will make the code slower.  Leveraging `in` is pretty hard work, you first need a pretty good reason to try it and only a profiler can tell you whether it is worth a shot.  Not common.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A key factor here is size; `Span<T>` / `ReadOnlySpan<T>` are deliberately *very small*, so the difference between a span and a reference-to-a-span is tiny. One key usage for `in` here is for *larger* readonly structs, to avoid a significant stack copy; note that there's a trade-off: the `in` is really a `ref`, so you're adding an extra layer of indirection to all access, unless the JIT sees what you're doing and works some voodoo. And of course: if the type *doesn't* declare itself as `readonly` then a stack copy is automatically added *before* the call to preserve the semantics.

Comment: I had an impression that `ref readonly` structs, such as `Span` and `ReadOnlySpan` already passed by reference (they even named like "ref-like types"), that seems not true?

Comment: @Evk the `ref` in `ref struct` just means "only allowed on the stack" (and therefore: allowed to hold ref-like types and managed pointers as fields); it doesn't mean it is passed by reference; and some of the most useful `ref struct` types are actually deliberately mutable. The `readonly` modifier enforces certain semantics allowing it to be used reliably in terms of no unexpected changes, which allows `in` to perform a copy-free `ref` call while guaranteeing (at least at the language level, not at the IL level) that the value will not be modified.

Comment: @Evk the key key thing is that it allows you to have (for example) a span field, which isn't allowed otherwise - or any other ref-like type (which muse likewise only ever exist on the stack)

Comment: Yes I think I understand the intention, but for some reason I also had impression they are also passed by ref. Maybe that "ref" in definition confused me. They could use some more meaningful name, like "stackonly" or something.

Comment: @Evk adding keywords - even contextual keywords - is harder than re-purposing and overloading an existing reserved keyword :)

Comment: I was going to use `Span<byte>` to pass a possibly big `readonly byte` array to an other method. Should I now pass it with the `in` parameter or as a `Span<byte>`? I thought `Span` was the answer, but now I see that according to the benchmarks, by reference seems a lot faster. Even passing the struct by value is faster. Can anyone explain?

Comment: @ElMac can you be very explicit what things you're comparing? A span *value* essentially *is* a reference/length pair (insert note about 2-field vs 3-field span, but... that's close enough); if you're passing a `Span<byte>`, there's no need to use `in` with it, as it is already small

Comment: @MarcGravell I believe I misunderstood what `Span<T>` was for. I expected its performance to be very similar to passing a `byte[]` array as a reference. If I pass a `Span<byte>`, I believe the byte array will not be copied, but why is it so much slower than even passing a `byte[]` array by value then (see @Tagc benchmark)? Now I am not sure, if I am wrong by comparing the benchmark, which used a struct to a `byte[]`.

Comment: @ElMac I think you're comparing invalid things; `PassLargeStructByValue` is meaningful to compare to `PassLargeStructByRef`, and `PassSpanByValue` is meaningful to compare to `PassSpanByRef` - but you can't compare in the other axis; they do other different things; IMO the most likely delta here is the contstant creation of array => span; the tests would be better with `ReadOnlySpan<byte> span = _data; for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++) AcceptSpanByValue(span);`

Comment: I ran the same benchmark code using .NET Core 2.2 and that delta seems to have disappeared (updated my answer to include the new benchmarks).

Comment: There is only an advance passing structs by ref is when they are already on the heap.

Comment: @Jeroen how do you figure that? There's no difference between stack and heap - they're both just memory (although one might be fresher in terms of page faults); an oversized struct is expensive to copy lots of times no matter where it originated from. And semantically, ref expresses something specific re mutability.

Comment: @MarcGravell true, I didn't realize that passing a (heap)struct to a method always results in a copy action. I love the `in` keyword for that.

Answer (score 13):

Marc's answer seems spot-on. I'm posting this just to supplement his own answer with some benchmarks that confirm what he's saying.

I set up the following benchmark class:

```
public class SpanBenchmarks
{
    private const int Iterations = 100_000;

    private byte[] _data;
    private LargeStruct _control;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void GlobalSetup()
    {
        _data = new byte[1000];
        new Random().NextBytes(_data);

        _control = new LargeStruct(_data[0], _data[1], _data[2], _data[3], _data[4], _data[5]);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void PassSpanByValue()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++) AcceptSpanByValue(_data);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void PassSpanByRef()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++) AcceptSpanByRef(_data);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void PassLargeStructByValue()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++) AcceptLargeStructByValue(_control);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void PassLargeStructByRef()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++) AcceptLargeStructByRef(_control);
    }

    private int AcceptSpanByValue(ReadOnlySpan<byte> span) => span.Length;
    private int AcceptSpanByRef(in ReadOnlySpan<byte> span) => span.Length;
    private decimal AcceptLargeStructByValue(LargeStruct largeStruct) => largeStruct.A;
    private decimal AcceptLargeStructByRef(in LargeStruct largeStruct) => largeStruct.A;

    private readonly struct LargeStruct
    {
        public LargeStruct(decimal a, decimal b, decimal c, decimal d, decimal e, decimal f)
        {
            A = a;
            B = b;
            C = c;
            D = d;
            E = e;
            F = f;
        }

        public decimal A { get; }
        public decimal B { get; }
        public decimal C { get; }
        public decimal D { get; }
        public decimal E { get; }
        public decimal F { get; }
    }
}
```

I repeated the same benchmark job three times with this and got similar results each time:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.13, OS=Windows 10 Redstone 3 [1709, Fall Creators Update] (10.0.16299.248)
Intel Core i7-4790 CPU 3.60GHz (Haswell), 1 CPU, 8 logical cores and 4 physical cores

Frequency=3507500 Hz, Resolution=285.1033 ns, Timer=TSC
.NET Core SDK=2.1.300-preview2-008354
  [Host]     : .NET Core 2.0.6 (CoreCLR 4.6.26212.01, CoreFX 4.6.26212.01), 64bit RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 2.0.6 (CoreCLR 4.6.26212.01, CoreFX 4.6.26212.01), 64bit RyuJIT


                 Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
----------------------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|
        PassSpanByValue | 641.71 us | 0.1758 us | 0.1644 us |
          PassSpanByRef | 642.62 us | 0.1524 us | 0.1190 us |
 PassLargeStructByValue | 390.78 us | 0.2633 us | 0.2463 us |
   PassLargeStructByRef |  35.33 us | 0.3446 us | 0.3055 us |
```

Using a large struct as a control, I confirm there are significant performance advantages when passing them by reference rather than by value. However, there are no significant performance differences between passing a `Span<T>` by reference or value.

---

**September 2019 Update**

Out of curiosity, I ran the same benchmarks again using .NET Core 2.2. There seem to have been some clever optimisations introduced since last time to reduce the overhead of implicitly casting an array to a `Span<T>`:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.11.5, OS=Windows 10.0.17134.984 (1803/April2018Update/Redstone4)
Intel Core i7-4700HQ CPU 2.40GHz (Haswell), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=2.2.106
  [Host]     : .NET Core 2.2.4 (CoreCLR 4.6.27521.02, CoreFX 4.6.27521.01), 64bit RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 2.2.4 (CoreCLR 4.6.27521.02, CoreFX 4.6.27521.01), 64bit RyuJIT


|                 Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|----------------------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|
|        PassSpanByValue |  39.78 us | 0.1873 us | 0.1660 us |
|          PassSpanByRef |  41.21 us | 0.2618 us | 0.2186 us |
| PassLargeStructByValue | 475.41 us | 1.3104 us | 1.0943 us |
|   PassLargeStructByRef |  39.75 us | 0.1001 us | 0.0937 us |
```